# Approved graph action does not work

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, publish

I've struggled with this for hours... new to creating graph actions... why doesn't our approved graph action work? We expect that when a user clicks the "Click Here!" button that it will show that they've scheduled a blood donation on their timeline.  We have a form button coded precisely as outlined in the FB tutorial, and it's on a page tab we've added to a page, but nothing happens when you click the "Click Here!" button.

The page tab in question -> http://www.facebook.com/cityofhope.donateblood/app_323470837712150

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function postSchedule()
  {
   FB.api(
    '/me/cohblooddonor:schedule',
    'post',
    { blood_donation: 'http://www.cityofhope.org/giving/Documents/blood-donor.html' },
    function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert('Error occured');
       } else {
          alert('You've shared with your friends! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
    });
 }
 </script>
```

And the button:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click here!" onclick="postSchedule()" />
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated! I've been going at this for hours.  Is it an authentication issue?  thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You've got a syntax error due to mismatched quotes on line 58 of your source: '**You**'ve ...'

You could escape the literal apostrophe with a backslash, or change "You've" to "You have".

You also have a few other errors on the page. Check these out using the Javascript console on a modern browser.

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that syntax error!  We ended up using a feed dialog (direct URL) instead of this jscript method, though. It more efficiently accomplishes what we needed.  Thanks for the help!  [link]http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/